# Attaching ArcGIS image server dataset in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, image-service

I have tried adding the dataset in QGIS using 
'qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer()'. But it throws this error.

> Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset
>   http://precisionedgeag.com:8080/arcgis/rest/services/ImageServices/RapidEye_R_NDVI?f=json&pretty=true:
>   `C:\DOCUME~1\15937.DSM\LOCALS~1\Temp\file.dat' not recognized as a
>   supported file format. Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider:
>   gdal, URI:
>   http://precisionedgeag.com:8080/arcgis/rest/services/ImageServices/RapidEye_R_NDVI?f=json&pretty=true

How to add this ArcGIS server (Imageservice dataset) in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

At this time you can't add Image Services into QGIS, there is no plugin. Image services can be loaded into ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro, or ArcGIS Online.